# How to change Plotly express scatterplot continuous colormap?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I was plotting a scatterplot in plotly express as the attached pics. Here the size of points are based on the number of occurrence (more occurrence= larger size of point) [image]

But I am unable to change the colormap of the figure. I tried using the continuous colormap keyword for scatter plot as well as generate colormap in matplotlib and then use it in plotly and both didnt work.

I am looking for a continuous colormap consists of yellow (low value) blue (mid range values) and red (high range values).

My current code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.colors
A= pd.read_csv('example.csv')
dA= A['ML']
dB= A['Radio']
dC= A['Occur']

norm=plt.Normalize(-1,1)
cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", 
["yellow","mediumblue","orangered"])

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.scatter(A, x="ML", y="Radio", color="Occur",color_discrete_sequence= 
["red", "blue", "yellow"]
             ,size='Occur')
fig.update_layout(
font_family="Times New Roman",
legend_title_font_color="green" ,
paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
xaxis = dict(
    tickmode = 'linear',color= '#000000',
    tick0 = 0,
    dtick = 15
),
yaxis = dict(
    tickmode = 'linear',color= '#000000',
    tick0 = 0,
    dtick = 1
),
font=dict(
    family="Times New Roman",
    size=18,
    color='#000000'
)
)
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
```

Comment: Does [How to correctly use colormaps for plotly express line mapbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575172/how-to-correctly-use-colormaps-for-plotly-express-line-mapbox) help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continuous colormap specification is 'color_continuous_scale'. If any color is specified here, it will be processed on the plotly side. If the color range is set arbitrarily, a tuple of the range value and color is specified. For data and code, please refer to the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#explicitly-constructing-a-color-scale).

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()

fig = px.scatter(df,
                 x="sepal_width",
                 y="sepal_length",
                 color='petal_length',
                 color_continuous_scale=[(0,'yellow'), (0.5, 'blue'), (1,'red')],
                 template='plotly_white'
                )

fig.show()
```

[image]